# Fatal error: Call to a member function the_meta() wpalchemy

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

I'm having error when i call the_meta() from single.php, im using wordpress 3.4.1, and WordPress Alchemy Metabox Class 1.4.17, my functions.php

```
include_once ( get_template_directory() .'/metaboxes/setup.php');
include_once( get_template_directory() .'/metaboxes/custom-spec.php');
```

my setup.php

```
    include_once WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/wpalchemy/MetaBox.php';
    include_once WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/wpalchemy/MediaAccess.php';

// include css to help style our custom meta boxes
add_action( 'init', 'my_metabox_styles' );

function my_metabox_styles()
{
    if ( is_admin() ) 
    { 
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wpalchemy-metabox', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/metaboxes/meta.css' );
    }
}

$wpalchemy_media_access = new WPAlchemy_MediaAccess();
```

custom-spec.php

```
<?php
$custom_mb = new WPAlchemy_MetaBox(array
(
    'id' => '_custom_meta',
    'title' => 'My Custom Meta',
    'template' => get_stylesheet_directory() . '/metaboxes/custom-meta.php',
));
```

and single.php

```
<?php //inside loop.......... ?>
<?php global $custom_mb ?>
<?php echo $custom_mb->the_meta();?>
```

ERROR is :Fatal error: Call to a member function the_meta() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\wp\wp-content\themes\twentyeleven\single.php on line 19

pleas help me to find the cause of error

Comment: I don't know wpalchemy but isn't it in the plugin dir? you include  `/wp-content/wpaclchemy/...` not `/wp-content/plugin/wpaclchemy/...`

Comment: Nice! The `global` 'trick' should always be in the back of your mind when working on independent php files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that the global $custom_mb is most probably nothing. So asking it to have a value is what is causing the error.

It does look like you have the correct code as per example here: http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/

Use `print_r($custom_mb);` after the global to see what it holds. If it's nothing you know somethings wrong.

Also, the code you say is inside the loop should be just outside of it.

(Update) **FIX:** Add `global $custom_mb;` to the top of the new php page.

Comment: Thanks it works, i forgot to put global $custom_mb in custom-spec.php.